# java sql query error

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

I have this code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class DBConntest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?user=root&useSSL=false", "root", "root");
        System.out.println("Connection succes!");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query1 = "USE test; insert into dbtester(name,age,email) values ('Aram',18,'aram@gmail.com');";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query1);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);;
    }

    }

}
```

I use Eclipse, and after run it return this error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into dbtester(name,age,email) values ('Aram',18,'aram@gmail.com')' at line 1

Same SQL Query work in MySQL workbench. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Change the line to `String query1 = "insert into dbtester(name,age,email) values ('Aram',18,'aram@gmail.com');";`

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line to `String query1 = "insert into dbtester(name,age,email) values ('Aram',18,'aram@gmail.com');";`

For no database selected exception :
Your URL for your database should include your database name. This is normally your URL followed by a "/databasename".

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename";
String username = "test";
String password = "test";
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```